# No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of ‘it’

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know why this code fails in GHCI?

```
Prelude> let x = 4 in sum [(x^pow) / product[1.. pow] | pow <- [0.. 9]]

<interactive>:70:1:
    No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

Comment: The `(^)` operator expects the exponent to be an integral value, but the `(/)` operator only works on non-integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use div:

```
Prelude> let x = 4 in sum [(x^pow) `div` product[1.. pow] | pow <- [0.. 9]]
50
```

Notice the types of the operators:

```
Prelude> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a

Prelude> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

`/` is for fractional numbers `div` for integrals ones

If you need floating point result use (**) operator instead of (^):

```
Prelude> let x = 4 in sum [(x**pow) / product[1.. pow] | pow <- [0.. 9]]
54.15414462081129
```

Mind the types once more:

```
Prelude> :t (^)
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a

Prelude> :t (**)
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

Comment: This produces a result that is not what I want. 

`Prelude> let x = 4 in sum [(realToFrac (x ^ pow)) / realToFrac(product[1.. pow]) | pow <- [0.. 9]]` outputs
`54.15414462081129`
but 
`Prelude> let x = 4 in sum [(x ^ pow) div product[1.. pow] | pow <- [0.. 9]]`
outputs 
`50`

Comment: @GeoffreyGoh, show us your expected output, should it be a floating point number?

Comment: the expected output should be 54.15414462081129. I managed to do it by using realToFrac. is there another way?