# No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of ‘it’

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function, but I'm unable to find a proper solution. How can I fix this:

```
findLoot val [] = 0
findLoot val ((x:y:[]):xs) | val == 0 = 0.0
                           | val < y  = ((val*x)/y)
                           | val > y  = ((div val y)*x) + (findLoot (mod val y) xs)
```

The error is

```
 interactive:33:1:
     No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
     The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
     Note: there are several potential instances:
       instance HasResolution a => Fractional (Fixed a)
         -- Defined in ‘Data.Fixed’
       instance Integral a => Fractional (Ratio a)
         -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
       instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
       ...plus one other
     In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
     In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Input Sets are

```
Input 1:-
  val = 50
  ((x:y:[]):xs) = [[120, 30], [100,50],[60, 20]]
Output 1:-
  180.0000

Input 2:-
val = 10
((x:y:[]):xs) = [[500,30]]
Output 2:- 
166.6667
```

Comment: Looks like the dreaded monomorphism restriction (google that term) - it tries to determine the type of your numbers but cannot decide on one.

Comment: @Bergi is there a way to modify this? I am not able to think a proper solution.

Comment: Add an explicit type `findLoot :: Fractional a => a -> [a] -> a`

Comment: @Bergi as soon as i add this i am getting error at load time Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for findLoot :: Fractional a => a -> [a] -> a

Comment: Using both `div` and `/` looks wrong. What is the type of your numbers? You likely want only `/`  (floating point) or only `div` (integer division).

Comment: Or maybe have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34650949/1048572) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37144190/1048572)

Comment: @BalrajSingh Ah, it's `a -> [[a]] -> a`, I didn't realise you had a list of lists. Though actually a list of tuples seems to be more appropriate here.

Comment: @chi I need to get integer part of div when val > y and if val < y i need all the fraction part.

Comment: What are the intended types of `val`, `x`, `y`, and the result of `findLoot`?

Comment: @melpomene I have updated question with input and output sets.

Comment: @BalrajSingh OK, but what are the intended types?

Comment: @melpomene val, x, y are Integer type and result of findLoot is Floot type

Comment: Then `| val < y  = (fromIntegral val * fromIntegral x) / fromIntegral y` should work.

Comment: @melpomene same issue after applying the above change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Haskell can only do arithmetic on values of the same type. When you do `x + y` or `x * y` or `x == y`, then `x` and `y` must have the same type.

The second issue is that Haskell's numeric types fall (mainly) into two classes, integral and fractional numbers. Only integral types (such as `Integer`) support `div` and `mod`, and only fractional types (such as `Double`) support `/`.

Your code tries to use `div`, `mod`, and `/` with `x`, `y`, and `val`, which forces Haskell to look for a single type that is both fractional and integral. Such a type doesn't exist.

Here's a possible solution:

```
findLoot :: Integer -> [[Integer]] -> Double
findLoot val [] = 0
findLoot val ((x:y:[]):xs) | val == 0 = 0.0
                           | val < y  = fromIntegral (val * x) / fromIntegral y
                           | val > y  = fromIntegral (div val y * x) + findLoot (mod val y) xs
```

Here all inputs (`val`, `x`, `y`) are `Integer`s, which makes `div` and `mod` work, and the result is `Double`. Whenever fractional numbers are needed (for `/` and for adding to the result of the recursive `findLoot` call), `fromIntegral` is used to convert from `Integer` to `Double`.

Comment: Of note is that your explicit declaration of the type will make the compiler give more informative errors. Good practice pays off.